# How can I make the program save itself in Delphi 7

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, save

How can I make my Delphi 7 program save itself into a new location. For example the program is saved on my flash stick then when I run it I want it to save itself in c:\user \ (user name)

The above is the original question.

This is the code I tried using. The program runs perfectly but when I check the folder it was supposed to save it in it does not appear there.

```
 procedure TForm5.FormActivate(Sender: TObject);
  var source, dest : string;
 begin
  Source := 'project1.exe';
  Dest := 'C:\Users\Craig\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup';
  CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), False);
 end;
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Read the executable file name from Application.ExeName. And then call CopyFile to perform the copy.

```
Source := Application.ExeName;
Dest := ...;
CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), False);
```

---

Regarding your update:

1. The destination needs to be a file. You are attempting to copy a file to a path that specifies a folder.
2. You didn't check for errors. When you call an API function like `CopyFile`, you need to check the return value.

You want something like this:

```
Source := 'project1.exe';
Dest := 'C:\Users\...\Startup\project1.exe';
if not CopyFile(PChar(Source), PChar(Dest), False) then
  RaiseLastOSError;
```

Comment: Or `ParamStr(0)` will give you the application name if you are running a console application.

Comment: @LURD Indeed so, thank you. But I think it can give you a relative path. Is that right? In which case GetModuleFileName would do the job.

Comment: ParamStr(0) will give you full path plus exe name.

Comment: @LURD Are you sure? I don't have Delphi at hand now, but my recollection is that ParamStr parses the return value of GetCommandLine. And if the process is invoked by means of a relative path, or from a location in the search path, then you won't get a full path. Of course, I could well be mistaken.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. `Application.ExeName` calls `ParamStr(0)`. The ParamStr(0) call remains the same since the Turbo Pascal days.

Comment: And FTR, ParamStr(0) does call the Windows GetModuleFileName function.

Comment: In your question, your examples show some relatively safe paths. But, you need to be careful when copying files (especially an EXE) that you don't  trigger security (anti-virus...) software (including that in Windows itself). For example, in most versions of Windows in use today, if you are a non-administrative user, you can not copy a file to C:\Program Files without getting a UAC pop-up.

Comment: David Heffernan how would I make the destination folder the startup folder in windows. The path of the folder is C:\Users\*****\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup the stars are representing the user name. How would I get the user name of the user for the path.

Comment: Call `SHGetSpecialFolderPath` passing `CSIDL_STARTUP`

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
CopyFile(PChar(C:\OldFile.exe), PChar(C:\NewFile.exe), true);
```

Comment: Might be worth adding the application version to the new file name, other wise you will always overwrite the copy that was there if there was one.

Comment: It wont, i set the last bolean variable in CopyFile() to true,if you set it to true  and the Target file already exists, the copy fails.

Comment: so if the copy on the USB stick is newer it wont update the local copy on the pc if there is already a copy there

Comment: @Shaun Let's not get hung up on the final parameter to CopyFile. Craig can choose to set it how he likes. I would however point out that the code in this answer does not compile.